# add empty directory to tarfile

Tags: python, tar

How do I add an empty directory to a tarfile in python, without creating it on disk first?

Creating an empty directory in my local filesystem, and adding this to the tar-file is easy enough, but creates unnecessary overhead.

Creating one directly in the tar-file, however seems non-trivial.
My attempts looks like:

```
import tarfile

with tarfile.open("test.tbz2",mode='w:bz2') as t:
    t.add("conf_dir") # does not work
    t.add(tarfile.TarInfo("conf_dir")) # does not work
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [addfile()](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.addfile) and change the [TarInfo.type](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarInfo.type) to tarfile.DIRTYPE

```
import tarfile    

with tarfile.open("test.tbz2",mode='w:bz2') as f:
    t = tarfile.TarInfo('mydir')
    t.type = tarfile.DIRTYPE
    f.addfile(t)
```

Comment: Just coming in to warn people that you probably want this too:

t.mode = 0o755

Or else you won't be allowed to access the directory you extract from the tar.